# How to query a TFDMemTable

Tags: c++builder, firedac

I am trying to create a simple loop to process a `TFDMemTable`.  I've dropped a `TFDMemTable`, a `TFDQuery`, and a `TFDConnection` on a Form, and I think I have wired everything up correctly, but when I activate the query it gives back an error message that there is no such table as FDMemTable1.

Here is demo code of what I am trying:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "FireDac.Stan.Def.hpp"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Vic", 100, 30)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Jeong", 20, 20)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Christina", 400, 50)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Justina", 0, 60)));

    FDConnection1->ConnectionName = L"FDMemTable1";
    FDConnection1->DriverName = L"SQLite";
    FDConnection1->Connected = true;
    FDQuery1->Connection = FDConnection1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString x;
    FDQuery1->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM FDMemTable1";
    FDQuery1->Active = true;

    if (!FDQuery1->Eof) {
        x = FDQuery1->FieldByName(L"FullName")->AsString;
        
        ...

        FDQuery1->Next();
    }
}
```

How does one go about querying an existing `TFDMemTable`?

Comment: Have you looked at Embarcadero's `TFDMemTable` examples yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query an FDMemTable you can use FireDAC's `LocalSQL` facility.  Adding a TFDLocaSQL component to your form enables you to register one or more TDataSet-descendant dataset (using the `Add` method of its `Datasets`  property), such as your FDMemTable, to be the target of a SQL search using Sqlite's SQL implementation.  It should be more than adequate to execute your query and is very easy to use, once you've set it up.

See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Local_SQL_(FireDAC) for more information.

This is the code from an answer of mine which uses FireDAC's `localSQL` with an FDMemTable.  The code is written in Dellphi but should be trivial to translate into c++:

```
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;

  FDLocalSQL1.Connection := FDConnection1;
  FDLocalSQL1.DataSets.Add(FDMemTable1);

  FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from FDMemTable1 order by ID limit 5';
  FDQuery1.Active := True;
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer turned out to be as MartynA suggested.  Here was the final code that worked:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "FireDac.Stan.Def.hpp"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "AdvGrid"
#pragma link "AdvObj"
#pragma link "AdvUtil"
#pragma link "BaseGrid"
#pragma link "DBAdvGrid"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    FDMemTable1->Active = true;
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Vic", 100, 30)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Jeong", 20, 20)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Christina, 400, 50)));
    FDMemTable1->InsertRecord(ARRAYOFCONST((L"Justina", 0, 60)));

    FDConnection1->ConnectionName = L"FDMemTable1";
    FDConnection1->DriverName = L"SQLite";
    FDConnection1->LoginPrompt = false;
    FDConnection1->Connected = true;

    FDLocalSQL1->Connection = FDConnection1;
    FDLocalSQL1->DataSets->Add(FDMemTable1, L"FDMemTable1");
    FDLocalSQL1->Active = true;

    FDQuery1->Connection = FDConnection1;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString x;
    FDQuery1->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM FDMemTable1";
    FDQuery1->Active = true;

    if (!FDQuery1->Eof) {
        x = FDQuery1->FieldByName(L"FullName")->AsString;

        FDQuery1->Next();
    }
}
```